# How to use Django Form create multilevel dropdown list

Tags: python, django

How can I do if I want to create multilevel dropdown list.
When I select project it will list all item belong project.
My Models.py Code:

```
class Project(models.Model):
    project_code=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    project_name=models.CharField(max_length=100)
class UniPro:
    unique_together = ('project_code', 'project_name')

    def __unicode__(self):              # __unicode__ on Python 2
        return self.project_name


class Item(models.Model):
    itemProject=models.ForeignKey(Project)
    item_code=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    item_POcode=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    item_name=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    item_datetime=models.DateTimeField('updated datetime')
```

My Forms.py

```
class NameForm(forms.Form):
    pselec = forms.ModelChoiceField(label='project',
                                    queryset=Project.objects.all())
    iselec = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Item.objects.all(),
                                  empty_label="SELECT")
```

Comment: I assume you want to do this on a single form (as opposed to having a form that feeds another form)... http://dustindavis.me/dynamic-filtered-drop-down-choice-fields-with-django/ has one possible option ... unless there's a plugin I haven't seen (and there should be since this is a fairly common use case), you may have to do some work in javascript to do the dynamic filtering on the client side...